# What are the LOSS used in the image caption generation task

Tags: image, loss-function, caption

Recently I am learning about image caption generation, and I would like to know what LOSS is used in the image caption generation task. Or what are the indicators to measure the similarity between two sentences (Chinese).

I learned that there are some indicators for evaluating image description generation, such as CIDEr, SPICE and CLIP score, etc., whether they are related to the LOSS used in training